# SQL to Zend Framework

Tags: sql, select, zend-framework

I am trying to convert my SQL statement to a query statement in Zend Framework

```
SELECT COUNT( FechaCita ) AS Num_de_Citas, FechaCita FROM cita WHERE idEspecialista = 13018 GROUP BY FechaCita
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $select = $this->select()
                    ->from('cita', array('COUNT( FechaCita ) AS Num_de_Citas'), 'FechaCita' )
                    ->where('idEspecialista = ?',13018)
                    ->group('FechaCita');
    $this->fetchRow($select);
```

This is the query for Zend 1.12.

Please read this SO manual before posting a question [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with `fetchAll`

I post my solution

PHP code:

```
$select = $db   ->select()
                ->from(array('c'=>'cita'), array('numCitas' => 'COUNT(*)', 'FechaCita', 'idEspecialista'))
                ->where('c.idEspecialista = ?',$_GET['idEspSelect'])
                ->group('c.FechaCita');
$stmt = $select->query();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```